# Datastax cassandra seem to cache preparestatent

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

When my application runs a long time, everything works as well. But when I change type a column from int to text(Drop table and recreate), I caught a Exception:

```
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [INT <-> java.lang.String]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.createCodec(CachingCodecRegistry.java:609)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry$1.load(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:95)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry$1.load(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:92)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2276)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3973)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4957)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4963)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry.getCachedCodec(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:117)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.codecFor(CachingCodecRegistry.java:215)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.data.SettableByIndex.set(SettableByIndex.java:132)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.data.SettableByIndex.setString(SettableByIndex.java:338)
```

This exception appears occasionally. I'm using PreparedStatement to execute the query, I think it is cached from DataStax's driver.

I'm using AWS Keyspaces(Cassandra version 3.11.2), DataStax driver 4.6.
Here is my application.conf:

```
  basic.request {
    timeout = 5 seconds
    consistency = LOCAL_ONE
  }
  advanced.connection {
    max-requests-per-connection = 1024
    pool {
      local.size = 1
      remote.size = 1
    }
  }
  advanced.reconnect-on-init = true
  advanced.reconnection-policy {
    class = ExponentialReconnectionPolicy
    base-delay = 1 second
    max-delay = 60 seconds
  }
  advanced.retry-policy {
    class = DefaultRetryPolicy
  }
  advanced.protocol {
    version = V4
  }
  advanced.heartbeat {
   interval = 30 seconds
   timeout = 1 second
  }
  advanced.session-leak.threshold = 8
  advanced.metadata.token-map.enabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Java driver 4.x caches prepared statement - it's a difference from the driver 3.x.  From [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.8/manual/core/statements/prepared/):

> the session has a built-in cache, it’s OK to prepare the same string twice.

...

> Note that caching is based on: **the query string exactly as you provided it**: the driver does not perform any kind of trimming or sanitizing.

I'm not sure 100% about the source code, but the relevant entries in the cache may not be cleared up on the table drop.  I suggest to open the [JIRA against Java driver](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA), although, such type changes are often not really recommended - it's better to introduce new field with new type, even if it's possible to re-create table.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. Prepared statements are cached -- it's the optimisation that makes prepared statements more efficient if they are reused since they only need to be prepared once (the query doesn't need to get parsed again).

But I suspect that underlying issue in your case is that your queries involve `SELECT *`. Best practice recommendation (regardless of the database you're using) is to *explicitly* enumerate the columns you are retrieving from the table.

In the prepared statement, each of the columns are bound to a data type. When you alter the schema by adding/dropping columns, the order of the columns (and their data types) no longer match the data types of the result set so you end up in situations where the driver gets an `int` when it's expecting a `text` or vice-versa. Cheers!